# Clear forest / improvement before building?

Tags: civilization-6

Should I use a builder to clear forest before building on top of it?

(When there's a red question mark icon saying "Building here will remove the forest")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a rather subjective question, and the "correct" answer will vary according to game situation. It all depends on your priority.

I will say that I typically do not remove forrest by putting a district on top of it. Instead, I will produce something else, and chop the forrest to help produce it faster. When I have finished that thing, I will then start the district on the tile that previously had a forrest.

Comment: Remember that chopping a forest uses up a builder charge. It might not be worth it if chopping yields less than 1/3rd of a new builder.

Comment: True, that's definitely something to consider before chopping wildly. Woods also grant adjacency to holy site districts. Again, game situation and priority are king for this question.

Comment: What about improvements? They don't generate anything if removed?

Comment: That's correct.