# How do I know how many hammers I will get from chopping down a forest?

Tags: civilization-6

Originating from [this comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/292753/clear-forest-improvement-before-building#comment413305_292755), I can always see how much a new builder will cost in the city production screen. How do I know if it is worth it- i.e., how many hammers will I get from the builder's "Remove Forest" action?

Comment: The quick test I did for the comment mentioned didn't result in a clear value. In previous civ games, it depended on the distant to the city. In civ-6, it also seems to depend on the age. There might be other factors involved on top of those.

Answer (score 1):

If you mouse over the Remove Forest icon when the builder is on the tile, it should display the production amount it yields. I don't believe there's a way to check without the builder there.